# how to run a c program multiple times using bash script

Tags: bash

i have to write Create two directory Input and Output and Write a c code that reads a file and copy the content to another file.then  a) Write a shell script which will do this for 20 files. b) Must read the files from Input directory and output the file to Output directory. i have problem in the bash script part. help me please

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the path of source directory:"
read dir1
echo "Enter the path of the destination directory:"
read dir2

for f in dir1/*
do
    arg1=$dir1/$f
    arg2=$dir2/$f
    gcc program.c
    ./a.out $arg1 $arg2
done
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? "Help me please" is rather generic.

Comment: the c program(program.c) is not taking the arguments from bash. the program.c is working properly though. @Evert

Comment: Have you tried replacing `./a.out`  with simply `echo`? That may point to where your problem is, and how to solve it. Echo and print statements are a very good first aid when it comes to bugs. (Note: it's also easy to forget, say, a dollar sign.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- `for f in dir1/*` should be `for f in $dir1/*`
- The variable `$f` also contains the `$dir1` path.

Here's my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the path of source directory:"
read dir1
echo "Enter the path of the destination directory:"
read dir2

gcc program.c
CMD=$PWD/a.out

cd $dir1
for f in *
do
    $CMD $f $dir2/$f
done
```

Comment: Thank u so much.. @maxime